# I can't draw my current Position on a Nutiteq Map

Tags: gps, android-canvas, geometry, map-projections, nutiteq

I try to draw a blue translucent circle to show my actual GPS Position on `Nutiteq's Map` but it shows no circle.

I want to display something like this
[image]

My Code is the following
`Circle` Class

```
public Circle(MapView mapView, MapPos mapPostPoint, float radius, Paint paintFill, Paint paintStroke) {
        checkRadius(radius);
        this.mapView      = mapView;
        this.mapPostPoint = mapPostPoint;
        this.radius       = radius;
        this.paintFill    = paintFill;
        this.paintStroke  = paintStroke;

        this.gUtils = new GeometricUtils(this.mapView);
}

public synchronized boolean draw(MapPos point, Canvas canvas, float radius, float zoomLevel) {
        if (this.mapPostPoint == null || (this.paintStroke == null && this.paintFill == null)) {
                return false;
        }

        double latitude  = point.x;
        double longitude = point.y;

        MapPos screenPoint = mapView.worldToScreen(point.x, point.y, 0);
        float pixelX = (float) screenPoint.x;
        float pixelY = (float) screenPoint.y;


        float radiusInPixel = (float) gUtils.metersToPixels((double)this.radius, latitude, zoomLevel);

        if (this.paintStroke != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(pixelX, pixelY, radiusInPixel, this.paintStroke);
        }
        if (this.paintFill != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(pixelX, pixelY, radiusInPixel, this.paintFill);
        }

        return true;
}
```

with `GeometricUtils` Class as

```
...
private static final int tileSize = 256;
...

public double resolution(double latitude, float scaleFactor) {
    long mapSize = getMapSize(scaleFactor, tileSize);
    return Math.cos(latitude * (Math.PI / 180)) * earthCircumference / mapSize;
}   

// Here I get how many Pixels I need to represent a distance of "meters"
public double metersToPixels(double meters, double latitude, float zoom) {
    double res = resolution(latitude, zoom);

    return meters / res;

}   


public long getMapSize(float scaleFactor, int tileSize) {
        if (scaleFactor < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("scale factor: " + scaleFactor + " should be >= 1 ");
        }
        return (long) (tileSize * (Math.pow(2, scaleFactorToZoomLevel(scaleFactor))));
}


public double scaleFactorToZoomLevel(double scaleFactor) {
       return Math.log(scaleFactor) / Math.log(2);
}
```

And last `MyLocationCircle` Class

```
public class MyLocationCircle {

private final   GeometryLayer layer;
private MapView mapView;

private MapPos  circlePos       = new MapPos(0, 0);
private float   circleScale     = 0;
private float   circleRadius    = 1;
private float   projectionScale = 0;
private boolean visible = false;
private Circle  circle;
private Paint   fill            = new Paint();
private Paint   stroke          = new Paint();
private Canvas  canvas          = new Canvas();

public MyLocationCircle(GeometryLayer layer, MapView mapView, double radius) {
    // Initialize Paint
    initializeGraphics();
    //

    this.layer        = layer;
    this.mapView      = mapView;
    this.circleRadius = (float)radius;
    this.circle       = new Circle(this.mapView, this.circlePos, this.circleRadius, this.fill, this.stroke);

}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public void setLocation(Projection proj, Location location) {
    circlePos = new MapPos(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());//proj.fromWgs84(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

    projectionScale = (float) proj.getBounds().getWidth();
    circleRadius = location.getAccuracy();

}

public void draw(MapPos position) {
    float zoom = mapView.getZoom();
    circle.draw(position, canvas, circleRadius, zoom);      
}

public MapPos getLocation() {
    return circlePos;
}

protected void initializeGraphics() {

    fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    fill.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    fill.setAlpha(60);

    stroke = new Paint();
    stroke.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);        
    stroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    stroke.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}
```

}

I turn the geo coordinates right into screen coordinates, because I can reverse right with the method `screenToWorld(...)` Method and I get right geo coordinates, so, **what am I making wrong?**

I can draw `Polygons`, `Lines`, `Markers`, `Labels`, etc so I can attach to Map via right Layers but I can't display a simple `Canvas` Circle on a Map.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample misses many important parts. How do you use your Canvas, how it is added to the Layout and how it relates to MapView? What calls circle.draw?

Nutiteq wiki has [GPS circle sample](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Draw-circle), did you check this? This adds Polygon object to map, and manipulates this using map coordinates, this way you do not need to know anything about screen coordinates, all this is handled by Nutiteq Maps SDK.

Comment: Hi Jaak, I didn't want to occupy so much place. I know your example but I want to draw a circle like `GoogleMaps` for that I used your `MyLocationCircle` where you draw a growing `n-side Polygon` as growing `Circle`. My `Circle` Class is above, directly under the Picture. I call properly my `Canvas` Object in that Class (`Circle`). I tried to add the circle as an "extension" of `Geometry` to my `GeometryLayer` and without extending `Circle` Class but successless.

Comment: I think, it would be better to ask you whether Nutiteq allows to draw a Circle with the Call `canvas.drawCircle(...)`. If so, where.  Thank you

Comment: Jaak, I actually develop an android prototype under `nutiteq` and wanted to display a perfect circle like `GoogleMaps`. I just wanted to know how I can self draw a circle via canvas but I can't "invest" so long for that. I'll do it how I first did, so, as `n vertices Polygon` as in `HelloMap3d`. I hope you can take soon a while to add to `Geometry` Class `Ellipse` - `Circle` Sub-Classes. That would be great, as you'd put the icing on the cake ;)